# Quotients and regular epimorphism

Tags: category-theory, epimorphisms

In category theory, is a quotient the same as a regular (or extremal?) epimorphism? (Just like a subobject corresponds to a regular mono.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes subobject (resp. quotient) means monomorphism (resp. epimorphism), sometimes it means regular monomorphism (resp. regular epimorphism). What it means depends on context. It is common to see subobject = monomorphism but quotient = regular epimorphism, because that is what works in many examples.